# Dealing with error

Tags: ios, core-data

Here's my code:

```
NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self.applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DB.sqlite"]];

- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
}
```

It gives me the error: expected identifier...what identifier?

Comment: why did u use lastobject

Answer (score 1):

Call method in proper way. `dot`(.)is used for accessing `properties`.Use s`pace( )` instead of `dot(.)`

```
NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DB.sqlite"]];

- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
}
```

Comment: LOL :D Thanks...I didn't saw that

Comment: FYI:expected identifier error is always something like syntax errors or bracket missing, extra brackets .